# How is it possible for const_get to have side effects?

Tags: ruby

The following Pry session is inexplicable. I called `const_get`, which AFAIK just gets a constant, and somehow, `require` gets called (and fails with an error). But it can't be a `const_missing` hook because the constant is defined, as can be seen by looking at the output of the `constants` method (and also by looking at the return value of `const_defined?`) (neither `constants` nor `const_get` appear to be monkeypatched):

```
bash-3.2$ pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'rack' # rack-2.0.3 installed
=> true
[2] pry(main)> Rack::Session
=> Rack::Session
[3] pry(main)> Rack::Session.constants
=> [:Cookie, :Pool, :Memcache]
[4] pry(main)> Rack::Session.const_defined?(:Memcache)
=> true
[5] pry(main)> Rack::Session.const_get(:Memcache)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- memcache
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
[6] pry(main)> wtf????
Exception: LoadError: cannot load such file -- memcache
--
 0: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 1: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 2: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/memcache.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 3: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 4: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 5: (pry):4:in `const_get'
 6: (pry):4:in `__pry__'
 7: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:355:in `eval'
 8: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:355:in `evaluate_ruby'
 9: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:323:in `handle_line'
10: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in eval'
11: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:242:in `catch'
12: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:242:in `block in eval'
13: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:241:in `catch'
14: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:241:in `eval'
15: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/repl.rb:77:in `block in repl'
16: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
17: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
18: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
19: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `__with_ownership'
20: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:79:in `with_ownership'
21: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
22: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/repl.rb:15:in `start'
23: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:169:in `start'
24: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.4.2/lib/pry-byebug/pry_ext.rb:11:in `start_with_pry_byebug'
25: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/cli.rb:219:in `block in <top (required)>'
26: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/cli.rb:83:in `block in parse_options'
27: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/cli.rb:83:in `each'
28: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/lib/pry/cli.rb:83:in `parse_options'
29: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.10.4/bin/pry:16:in `<top (required)>'
30: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/bin/pry:22:in `load'
31: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/bin/pry:22:in `<main>'
[7] pry(main)> Rack::Session.method(:constants).source_location
=> nil
[8] pry(main)> Rack::Session.method(:const_get).source_location
=> nil
[9] pry(main)> Rack::Session.method(:const_missing).source_location
=> nil
[10] pry(main)> Rack::Session.method(:const_defined?).source_location
=> nil
```

Comment: I found the answer already: If the body of a class calls `autoload :ConstantName, 'some/file'`, that constant shows up as being defined, even though it isn't. How irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the body of a class does this:

```
class Foo
  autoload :ConstantName, 'some/file'
end
```

...that constant shows up as being defined, even though it isn't. That's one way the very act of evaluating a constant can have side effects such as stuff being printed to the terminal, network connections being opened, and really anything you can imagine being placed in the body of a source file.

```
Foo::ConstantName # Possibly opens your web browser
                  # and points it to something vulgar.
                  # Then installs a rootkit.
```